# How to set value of the Text filed equal to the JTable cell

Tags: java, jtable, jtextfield

I am trying to update the value of the `JTextFiwld` to be equal to `JTable` cell one of the user told me to use `setText()` but this is not the way java going to recognize the cell even if he did how he will get the value from the cell and update it to the `JTextField` because every row have 3 cells also I am using `SwingWorker` to read files then show the information in the `JTable` then the information should be showing in the text field do I have to use `ActionListener` or what?

```
public class GuiInterface extends JFrame {
    String[] columnNames = {"#", "Start", "End", "Translation column"};


    ReadFile reader;
    private final int numberOfButton = 6;
    private final JTable table;
    JToolBar toolBar;
    private final JTextField enterText,startTime,endTime;
    private final JMenu jMenu1,jMenu2,jMenu3;
    private final JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private final JMenuItem itemNewSrt,itemOpenVideo,itemSavefile;
    private static JFileChooser ourFileSelector,ourVideoSelector;
    File ourVideoFile,ourSrtFile;
    Border Campound,empty,Boveld,etch;
    private final JLabel startTimeingLable,endTimeingLabel;
    public static String  mediaPath="",srtPath="";
    Canvas c;
    ImageIcon[] icon;
    JButton[] Obutton;
   static final int COLUMN = 4 ; 



         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
       {
           //ReadFile.readSubtitles();
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GuiInterface("");

            }

        });

}



    public GuiInterface(String title){

    //reader = new ReadFile();

    setSize(1024, 720);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("AnimeFactor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(GuiInterface.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //video setting 
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    c = new Canvas();
    c.setBackground(Color.black);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
    mediaPlayer.playMedia("C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4");
    table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);


    ImageIcon openIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/folder-icon.png"));
        ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/red-disk-icon.png"));
        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/Actionsnew-icon.png"));




        Action openAction = new AbstractAction("Open Subtitle", openIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ourFileSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                ourFileSelector.showSaveDialog(null);
                ourSrtFile =  ourFileSelector.getSelectedFile();
                srtPath = ourSrtFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Worker p = new Worker(srtPath, table);
                p.execute();
            }
        };

        Action saveAction = new AbstractAction("Save", saveIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        };
        Action newAction = new AbstractAction("New", newIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("New File");
            }
        };
    jMenu1 = new JMenu("File");
    jMenu2 = new JMenu("Video");
    jMenu3 = new JMenu("Subtitle");
    itemNewSrt = new JMenuItem(newAction);
    jMenu1.add(itemNewSrt);
    itemSavefile = new JMenuItem(saveAction);
    jMenu1.add(itemSavefile);
    jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
    jMenuBar1.setBorder(etch);
    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);
    ourFileSelector = new JFileChooser();

    Obutton = new JButton[numberOfButton];
    etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    //starting and ending time
    enterText = new JTextField();
    enterText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,100));
    startTime = new JTextField("0:00:00.00 ");

    startTime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
    startTimeingLable = new JLabel("Starting Time");
    endTimeingLabel = new JLabel("Ending Time");
    endTime = new JTextField("0:00:00.00 ");
    endTime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
    //end of start and ending time filed

        toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
        toolBar.add(newAction);
        toolBar.add(saveAction);


        JPanel toolBarPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        toolBarPane.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel timing = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        timing.add(startTimeingLable);
        timing.add(startTime);
        timing.add(endTimeingLabel);
        timing.add(endTime);


        empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 5, 5, 5);
        Boveld = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED);
        Campound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty,Boveld);


        JPanel textFiled = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textFiled.add(timing);
        textFiled.add(enterText,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        textFiled.setBorder(Campound);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(textFiled, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(toolBarPane,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);





       toolBar.add(openAction);
       itemOpenVideo = new JMenuItem(openAction);
       jMenu1.add(itemOpenVideo);
       //itemOpenVideo.addActionListener(new MenuBarMethod());
       JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); 
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);

    }


     class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void> {
       private final String srtPath;
       private final JTable table;
       DefaultTableModel model;
        public Worker(String srtPath, JTable table) {
                this.srtPath = srtPath;
                this.table = table;
             }


     @Override
      protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground() {
     model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    ArrayList<String> ends = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> starts = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> subs = ReadFile.readSubtitles(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> lins = ReadFile.ArraylineLengths(srtPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < ReadFile.maxLine(srtPath); i++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {lins.get(i), starts.get(i), ends.get(i), subs.get(i)});
    }
    return model;
}
    @Override
     protected void done() {
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
}
}



public class MenuBarMethod implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        Object buttonPressed=a.getSource();
       if(buttonPressed.equals(itemOpenVideo)){
        ourVideoSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        ourVideoSelector.showSaveDialog(null);
        ourVideoFile = ourVideoSelector.getSelectedFile();
        mediaPath = ourVideoFile.getAbsolutePath();
       }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: When should the field be updated?

Comment: after loading the file it should show the first cell (row) when the user move to the next using mouse or keyboard the information updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by adding a `ListSelectionListener` to the table...

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    }
});
```

This will let you know when the row selection has changed.

In the `valueChanged` method, you want to determine which row has been selected...

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
```

Then you will want to get the value for the specified column...

```
Object value = table.getValueAt(row, 0); 
// 0 represents the first column, change per your requirements...
```

Now, assuming that the value is simply a `String` you could simply use something like...

```
enterText.setText(value == null ? null : value.toString());
```

If the `value` is an `Object` of some other type, you need to cast it first and extract the required information

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: the ListSelectionListener is the inside constrictor right

Comment: Where ever you want, but yes, might be better to add it sooner rather then later

Comment: what value == null ? null mean in java

Comment: It's short hand for `if (value == null) {...} else {...}`. It's possible that the model might return a `null` value. It's known as a [Ternery Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)

Comment: ok what if i wanna to tell java after changing the value and moving to the next cell set the value of the cell to the changed value

Comment: but this have to be int table.setValueAt(enterText, row, value3); i mean value3

Comment: all lines are string and when i use this way and click at any line the blue color not moving to the next

Comment: i think it have to be enterText.getText() first to get the text after changing the value then getSelectedRow then setValueAt

Comment: can you take look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206984/how-to-set-value-of-the-text-filed-equal-to-the-jtable-cell

Comment: i think for setValueAt i have to use this.addTableModelListener(new sampleTabelModelListener()); and also fireTableCellUpdated to update the cell

Comment: this is the answer i think but i did not try it yet http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/181756-getting-jtable-to-recognize-changes-made-to-a-cell/

Comment: That's pretty much what I said

Comment: Here's an idea, rather then trying to take text from the text fields and apply it to the table, why not make the table editable?

Comment: do you wanna me to remove text filed

Comment: Personally, I think it would be easier

Comment: ok if i remove the textfileds can you help me also the timing filed in the jtable starting time and ending time must be like this 00:00:00:00 so i used text filed to stop user from adding different value using jtextfiled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51382/discussion-between-jack-peton-and-madprogrammer)